# How to achieve common border on a complex CALayer form (toolip)?

Tags: ios, calayer

I need to display a tooltip with text insider and border - like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngBOV.jpg

I can implement the form by combining rounded corders Rectangle form and Triangle form attached to bottom. If I do no need a border, this is sufficient - forms overlap each other and you get one merged form displayed.

However if I start applying border then it will draw border around each form, which is not what I want - I need a border around the whole figure.

Is there any method to achieve this?  I have seen that if group figures to parent layer and apply shadow property on this layer I get the shadow behind the merged figure - so I'd need the same with border/stroke.

Answer (score 1):

if using `imageView` as background, you could use `half` of the image and  `resizableImageWithCapInsets` to whatever size you want, and then add another flipped image. an example as:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "half") //(126, 165) only
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
imageView.image = image //looks bad
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 26, left: 26, bottom: 70, right: 60)
imageView.image = image?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(insets) //looks nice
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After posting here I found the solution: I create another set of figures, increase them in size to 1 pixel in each direction, assign different color and put them BENEATH front layers - this looks truly as a border!